# UseEffect not fired when redux props change caused by async api call with redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a functional login page connected with redux, I'm firing an async event onSubmit that will trigger the `emailLogin` action, I am using `useEffect` to detect the change of the `isLoading` prop to see whether login finished or not. If login success, the redux store should have the user object, if failed, the user should remain null.

The question is, I know that the login is success, which should triggered the change of `isLoading`, the parameter that decide whether the `useEffect`, however, the `useEffect` is not fired. Also, the `console.log('done');` after the line `await emailLogin(authData);` is never fired. Ssomething is wrong.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { emailLogin } from '../actions/index';

function Login({ user, isLoading, emailLogin }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect fired', user, isLoading); //<-----This does not fire after login success
    if (user) {
      history.push('/protected_home');
    } 
  }, [isLoading]);

  const submitEmailLoginForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const authData = { email, password };
    await emailLogin(authData);
    console.log('done'); // <------- This is never fired
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <Link to="/">back</Link>
      <form onSubmit={submitEmailLoginForm}>
        <label>
          email:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          password:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
  isLoading: state.isLoading
});

const mapDispatch = {
  emailLogin: emailLogin
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(Login);
```

My action file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const authActions = {
  EMAIL_LOGIN_START: '@@EMAIL_LOGIN_START',
  EMAIL_LOGIN_SUCCESS: '@@EMAIL_LOGIN_SUCCESS'
};

export const emailLogin = ({ email, password }) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: authActions.EMAIL_LOGIN_START });
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5001/api/auth', {
      email: email,
      password: password
    });
    dispatch({
      type: authActions.EMAIL_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        user: { ...response.data }
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Should dispatch api error', error.response);
  }
};
```

My Reducer:

```
import { authActions } from '../actions/index';

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  isLoading: false
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case authActions.EMAIL_LOGIN_START:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case authActions.EMAIL_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      console.log('Reducer check => Login is success'); //<-----this line is printed
      return { ...state, user: action.payload.user, isLoading: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

In the reducer, I see that the success action is actually triggered by checking the `console.log()`. Also in the redux dev tool, I can actually see that the login is success and the `isLoading` prop has changed :
[image]

Comment: Is not what is causing your issue, but the `useEffect` call should receive both `[isLoading, user]` as dependencies.

Comment: @elyalvarado Good catch, but it's not even working with `isLoading` which has apparently changed so I wanna focus on that first

Comment: It changed twice: `false -> true -> false` maybe its doing it too fast and react is bailing on rendering the first change. Add the user and let me know if it works

Comment: where do you use the user reducer?

Comment: @TomMendelson currently my only reducer

Comment: @TomMendelson Thankyou, you reminded me of the missing `userReducer` in `state.userReducer.user`, React doesn't give me an error for that! Please post an answer so that I can give you the points :)

Comment: @elyalvarado As you have said, that is not causing the issue, but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solve my problem

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.userReducer.user,
  isLoading: state.userReducer.isLoading
});
```